# extract value of the same field from multiple list object in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list object as below:

```
structure(list(bga_u = structure(list(buy_target_price = numeric(0), 
    sell_target_price = numeric(0), units_holding = 0, tx_record = structure(list(
        `2010-12-01` = structure(list(buy_date = structure(14944, class = "Date"), 
            offer_price = 40.58, buy_unit = 3.15931809278285, 
            status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", "offer_price", 
        "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-01-03` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(14977, class = "Date"), offer_price = 42.2, 
            buy_unit = 3.03803621339166, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-02-01` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(15006, class = "Date"), offer_price = 42.59, 
            buy_unit = 3.01021667539629, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-03-01` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(15034, class = "Date"), offer_price = 43.37, 
            buy_unit = 2.95607858439309, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-04-01` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(15065, class = "Date"), offer_price = 43.35, 
            buy_unit = 2.95744240380919, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-05-03` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(15097, class = "Date"), offer_price = 44.53, 
            buy_unit = 2.87907316876551, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status"))), .Names = c("2010-12-01", 
    "2011-01-03", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-03"
    ))), .Names = c("buy_target_price", "sell_target_price", 
"units_holding", "tx_record")), bwg_u = structure(list(buy_target_price = numeric(0), 
    sell_target_price = numeric(0), units_holding = 0, tx_record = structure(list(
        `2010-11-02` = structure(list(buy_date = structure(14915, class = "Date"), 
            offer_price = 63.15, buy_unit = 2.03016830095215, 
            status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", "offer_price", 
        "buy_unit", "status")), `2010-12-01` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(14944, class = "Date"), offer_price = 64.19, 
            buy_unit = 1.99727571592348, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-09-01` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(15218, class = "Date"), offer_price = 69.29, 
            buy_unit = 1.85026884406304, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status")), `2011-10-03` = structure(list(
            buy_date = structure(15250, class = "Date"), offer_price = 58.05, 
            buy_unit = 2.20852934031229, status = "hold"), .Names = c("buy_date", 
        "offer_price", "buy_unit", "status"))), .Names = c("2010-11-02", 
    "2010-12-01", "2011-09-01", "2011-10-03"))), .Names = c("buy_target_price", 
"sell_target_price", "units_holding", "tx_record"))), .Names = c("bga_u", 
"bwg_u"))
```

This is a "list in a list" object composed of 3 levels:

- level 1: names of all fund (2 funds here: `bga`_u and `bwg_u`)
- level 2: target buy price; target sell price; and units holding
- level 3: details of a particular trade (e.g. unit bought)

The "unit holding" stored in level 2 is calculated by summing the "buy unit" in level 3 for each trade, if the status in for that particular trade is still "hold".

How can I calculate the "unit holding" for each fund and put in level 2?

(I used R for 2-3 years but I am new to the `list` object, I may be conceptually wrong about `list`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that whole list is named as `dl`, apply function to every first level (fund) of list. First, make data frames of trade records, then sum units and put them in `units_holding`.

```
for(i in 1:length(dl)){
  df<-do.call(rbind,lapply(dl[[i]]$tx_record,data.frame))
  dl[[i]]$units_holding<-sum(df$buy_unit[df$status=="hold"])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it (assuming the object is names `dat`):

```
lapply(dat, function(x) 
  "[[<-"(x, "units_holding", 
         sum(sapply(x[["tx_record"]], function(y) 
           ifelse(y[["status"]] == "hold", y[["buy_unit"]], 0)))))
```

In this command, `lapply` and `sapply` are used to iterate over the lists's first and second level, respectively.

Note. This creates a new object which you might wish to assign to a new variable (or overwrite the old one).

Comment: +1 beautiful mix lapply and sapply . Mybe it need some splaining for the OP, newbie to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that tries to make the operation performed in getting buy prices as opaque as possible. We return 0 if the `status` is not `hold`, so that summing it up doesn't affect the final total.

Generally, if you're traversing lists in R and are handling each component uniformly, you can use the `lapply` or `sapply` functions. This will probably be slow if you have an especially large number of transactions, though.

```
## assume your data is available in a variable 'dat'
get_buy_price <- function(x) {
  if( x[["status"]] == "hold" ) {
    return( x[["buy_unit"]] )
  } else {
    return( 0 )
  }
}

buy_prices <- sapply( dat, function( fund ) {
  sapply( fund["tx_record"], function( date ) {
    sapply( date, get_buy_price )
  })
})

totals <- lapply( buy_prices, sum )

for( fund_ind in seq_along(dat) ) {
  dat[[fund_ind]]$units_holding <- totals[[fund_ind]]
}
```